# How to use Oracle SQL/JSON in PL/SQL cursor?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I want to form a JSON from a cursor but when I use the below select query in the cursor, I'm getting "bad bind variable json_object", how to solve this problem? My database is Oracle 19C

```
select 
  JSON_OBJECT( 'Header':
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'SenderID': 'INS015',
        'PayerID': 'INS015'))
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expr: expr` syntax you are using was introduced in Oracle 19 so it should work, however, you can also use the original `KEY expr VALUE expr` syntax:

```sql
select JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'Header' VALUE JSON_OBJECT(
                              KEY 'SenderID' VALUE 'INS015',
                              KEY 'PayerID' VALUE 'INS015'
                            )
       )
from   dual;
```

As pointed out by [@astentx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76521582/how-to-use-oracle-sql-json-in-pl-sql-cursor/76521747?noredirect=1#comment134922865_76521747), there can be issues with client drivers that try to automatically identify bind variables and are generating false positive matches with the new syntax.

The [JSON Developer Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-1084A518-A44A-4654-A796-C1DD4D8EC2AA) states:

> **Note:** Some client drivers might try to scan query text and identify bind variables before sending the query to the database. In some such cases a colon as name–value separator in `json_object` might be misinterpreted as introducing a bind variable. You can use keyword `VALUE` as the separator to avoid this problem (`'Name' VALUE Diderot`), or you can simply enclose the value part of the pair in parentheses: `'Name':(Diderot)`.

So you could try using additional parentheses:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         'Header': (
                     JSON_OBJECT(
                       'SenderID': ('INS015'),
                       'PayerID': ('INS015')
                     )
                   )
       )
FROM   dual;
```

To prevent the client driver from generating false-positive matches for bind variables.

---

Separately, there appears to be a bug when the `expr: expr` syntax is used in PL/SQL as:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur FOR
    select JSON_OBJECT(
             'Header': JSON_OBJECT(
                         'SenderID': 'INS015',
                         'PayerID': 'INS015'
                       )
           ) AS json
    from   dual;
END;
/
```

In Oracle 21, gives the exception:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 7, column 36:
> PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
> ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> ```

(Even though the same SQL statement works in the SQL scope.)

But, by switching to the original `VALUE` separator:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur FOR
    select JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'Header' VALUE JSON_OBJECT(
                                  KEY 'SenderID' VALUE 'INS015',
                                  KEY 'PayerID' VALUE 'INS015'
                                )
           ) AS json
    from   dual;
END;
/
```

Then the statement works.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iQEhxACm)

Comment: This is described in [JSON Developer Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-1084A518-A44A-4654-A796-C1DD4D8EC2AA): ***Note**:Some client drivers might try to scan query text and identify bind variables before sending the query to the database. In some such cases a colon as name–value separator in `json_object` might be misinterpreted as introducing a bind variable. You can use keyword `VALUE` as the separator to avoid this problem, or you can simply enclose the value part of the pair in parentheses*

Comment: @astentx Agreed for client applications/drivers, however using the colon as a name-value separator does not appear to work in PL/SQL even without the problem of mistakenly interpreting the separator as a bind variable. I've tried getting the SQL statement to work when using `OPEN cur FOR` and `SELECT ... INTO` and they all raise syntax errors in PL/SQL even though the statement works in SQL.

Comment: It seems that it actually misinterpret it, producing different errors for function call (`json_object` produce ORA-00907) and for identifier (produce ORA-01008): https://dbfiddle.uk/oS8u8m77. However I didn't manage to trace tokenization to find why this may happen.

Comment: @astentx Parentheses solves the problem [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8vVmCv-C) (as does using `VALUE` for the separator).